# Is techelet from a non-Jew valid?

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

Can you purchase the techelet dye from a gentile?
Can you purchase tzitzit that have been dyed with techelet by them, is that valid?

Comment: Since tzitzit must be made lishmah, then we cannot use tzitzit made by a nonJew. I do not know about the techeilet.

Comment: @sabba tekhelet must be dyed lishmah, as it says in my answer below

Comment: @DoubleAA I had read the question as asking if the dye itself had to be made lishmah. That is why I phrased my comment that way.

Answer (score 3):

[Rambam, Laws of Tzitzit 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Fringes.2.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> התכלת אינה נלקחת, אלא מן המומחה--חוששין, שמא לא נצבעה לשמה.‏
> Tekhelet may not be purchased but from an expert, for we are concerned lest it not have been dyed for the sake of [the commandment]. (my translation)

Whether or not a gentile who makes an item for the sake of a commandment with a Jew standing there telling him to do so counts is a dispute between Rambam and Rosh (OC 11:2 etc.) though many later authorities advise being strict.

---

[Rambam, Laws of Tzitzit 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Fringes.2.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> המפקיד תכלת אצל הגוי--הרי זו פסולה, שמא החליפה.  ואם הייתה בכלי, והיה חתום בשני חותמות, חותם בתוך חותם--כשרה; בחותם אחד, פסולה.‏
> One who deposits Tekhelet with a gentile -- it is invalid, lest he exchanged it [for a cheaper fake]. And if it was in a vessel sealed with two seal, one seal within the other seal, it is valid. With one seal, it is invalid. (my translation)

If buying Tekhelet from a gentile you would need careful supervision and packaging to ensure nothing has been tampered with.